# Errors in my torch app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to create an app  for turning a torch on and off on android and I'm getting a few errors I cant work out. The errors only seem to come up in the java activity, and seem to be something to do with the 'cam' activity I made. At the bottom of my java cam.release when I hover it says 'Add cast'.

Thanks for your help in advanced.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    Camera cam;
    ToggleButton mTorch;
    Parameters camParams;
    private Context context;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private final int FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED = 0;
    private final int FLASH_TORCH_NOT_SUPPORTED = 1;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = MainActivity.this;
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            mTorch = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        } else {           
             showDialog(MainActivity.this,FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

    private void showDialog(MainActivity mainActivity, int fLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        mTorch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                try {
                    if (cam != null) {
                        cam = Camera.open();
                    }
                    camParams = cam.getParameters();
                    List<String> flashModes = camParams
                            .getSupportedFlashModes();
                    if (isChecked) {
                        if (flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
                            camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        } else {           
                             showDialog(MainActivity.this,FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                        }
                    } else {
                        camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    }
                    cam.setParameters(camParams);
                    cam.startPreview();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    cam.stopPreview();
                    cam.release();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (cam == null) {
            cam = Camera.open();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (cam != null) {
            cam.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        cam.release();

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.t.torch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.Camera"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.t.torch.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:text="ToggleButton" >
    </ToggleButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: define "i'm getting a few errors"

Comment: its basically every where there is a cam. or similar to this for example cam.stopPreview();
cam.release();

Comment: You're catching the exception; please let us know what that exception is, including its stack trace.

Comment: sorry bit of a newbie how do i find that out. Also to help you i have this error also   } else {           
    showDialog(MainActivity.this,FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED);
  }

Comment: which puts an error on the showDialog saying the activity is not applicable for the argument.

Comment: if there is an error at runtime, there should be a stacktrace, in which case, post it here

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that `cam` is never being set. You're probably getting NullPointerExceptions on any line related to that variable.

The cause is:

```
if (cam != null) {
    cam = Camera.open();
}
```

Which should of course be:

```
if (cam == null) {
    cam = Camera.open();
}
```

Also note that `cam` may be null during the invocation of `onStop()`.

Comment: this helps get rid of the error in cam however it doesnt here  if (cam != null) {cam.release();

Comment: Please be more specific. Which error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to get the stacktrace?!?!?!? :(

Comment: If you are developing in Eclipse, use the Logcat view. Otherwise use `adb logcat`.

Comment: ive got the logcat open but its blank and i tried running the program but it says fix errors.. this is what the top error says unhandled event loop exception

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation its really hard for me... anyway  cam.release(); in that bit of code theres a red line under release. and when i hover over it it says 'add cast to cam'. it also saya that onb some of the other ones with the similar layout.

Comment: Ah, you're seeing compilation errors. That wasn't clear to me. Make sure that none of your own classes are also called `Camera` and that you're importing `android.hardware.Camera`.

Comment: Hi sorry for the delayed reply. I imported the hardware and it came up with an error saying remove unused imports and non of my classes are called camera. I'm listing all the bits of my code which are highlighted red now in order.

Comment: cam = Camera.open(); ""THE METHOD OPEN IS UNDEFINED FOR TYPE CAMERA""
camParams = cam.getParameters(); ""ADD CAST TO 'CAM'""                  }else {               showDialog(MainActivity.this,FLASH_NOT_SUPPORTED); 
} ""showDialog in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, int)""cam.setParameters(camParams);
     cam.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     cam.stopPreview();
     cam.release();

Comment: SORRY i tried to make it as clear as i could. Just do your best :)

Comment: Your IDE (Eclipse?) cannot find the `android.hardware.Camera` class. Your problem lies in that you are somehow importing the wrong class, or that your classpath is incorrectly set up.